# Custom client-side checkbox column

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to implement client-side checkbox column for the grid using MVC Helper. This column must not be defined as property in Model and behave as client only. Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with a template column. I am not aware of the binding, which is used in the current scenario, so I am adding examples for both (ajax and server).

E.g. Server Binding

```
columns.Template(@<text><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" /></text>);
```

When an Ajax binding is used, you should bind the column to some property (regardless which) and specify a client template.
E.g.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' />").Title("Custom title");
```